# Fill and dodge boxplots by group on a continuous x axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, grouping, boxplot

I have been having issues with what seems to be a simple thing to do: grouped boxplots with a continuous x axis.

Here is come minimal data data:

```
df <- cbind(expand.grid(x=1:10, rep=1:20, fill=c("A", "B")), y=runif(400))
```

And here is what I want;  you will see I have forced the x axis to be discrete:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(x), y=y,  fill=fill)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

This is what I get when I leave `x` as continuous, without a grouping:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y,  fill=fill)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

When I add a grouping, the color disappears:

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=x, fill=fill)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

To be clear, what I would want in `geom_point` would be:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=x, color=fill)) + geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=.7))
```

[image]

...but if I try to set a dodge in boxplot:

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y,  color=fill)) + geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=.7))

[image]

Any tips?  I have tried searching around: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050802/how-to-create-geom-boxplot-with-large-amount-of-continuous-x-variables) addressed continuous boxplots, but without the coloring issue; [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999185/ggplot-multi-factor-level-grouping-for-boxplot-with-continuous-scale) makes me wonder if i need to set an interaction, but doesn't seem to get the desired results.  Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I know this is not what you asked, but you can achieve something similar (depending of the data will work) making groups by intervals on `x`. `ggplot(df, aes(x=cut_interval(x=x, length=1), y=y,  fill=fill)) + geom_boxplot()`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From `?aes_group_order`:

> By default, the group is set to the interaction of all discrete variables in the
>   plot.

In your data, you only have one discrete variable, "fill". However, we wish the data to be grouped by *both* "fill" *and* "x". Thus, we need to specify the desired grouping using the `group` argument. And yes, you were correct, `interaction` is the way to go.

First, a slightly smaller data set (easier to link data to output):

```
d <- data.frame(x = rep(c(1, 2, 4), each = 8),
                grp = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 4),
                y = sample(24))
```

Then the plot, where we group data by the different combinations of "x" and "grp" (`interaction(x, grp)`), and `fill` the boxes by "grp":

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, group = interaction(x, grp), fill = grp)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that works, **custom built for your own cut sizes**:

Take the original df:

```
{df <- cbind(expand.grid(x=1:10, rep=1:20, fill=c("A", "B")), y=runif(400))}
```

Use cut() to define where you want your x groups and use "dodge2" to position your graphs:

```
{ggplot(df, aes(x = cut(x, 5), y = y, fill = fill)) +
        geom_boxplot(position = "dodge2", outlier.alpha = 0.1)}
```

Boxplot with 5 custom groups with equal cuts between 1:10
[image: Boxplot with 5 custom groups with equal cuts between 1:10]